# scan memory of calling process

Tags: c, linux

I have to scan the memory space of a calling process in C. This is for homework. My problem is that I don't fully understand virtual memory addressing.

I'm scanning the memory space by attempting to read and write to a memory address. I can not use proc files or any other method.

So my problem is setting the pointers.

From what I understand the "User Mode Space" begins at address 0x0, however, if I set my starting point to 0x0 for my function, then am I not scanning the address space for my current process? How would you recommend adjusting the pointer -- if at all -- to address the parent process address space?

edit: Ok sorry for the confusion and I appreciate the help. We can not use proc file system, because the assignment is intended for us to learn about signals.

So, basically I'm going to be trying to read and then write to an address in each page of memory to test if it is `R`, `RW` or not accessible. To see if I was successful I will be listening for certain signals -- I'm not sure how to go about that part yet. I will be creating a linked list of structure to represent the accessibility of the memory. The program will be compiled as a 32 bit program.

With respect to parent process and child process: the exact text states

> When called, the function will scan the entire memory area of the calling process...

Perhaps I am mistaken about the child and parent interaction, due to the fact we've been covering this (fork function etc.) in class, so I assumed that my function would be scanning a parent process. I'm going to be asking for clarification from the prof.

[image: drawing of address space]

So, judging from this picture I'm just going to start from 0x0.

Comment: One major purpose of processes is to isolate memory access. None of the data from the parent process will be directly addressable in the child process. And the address space does not usually start at 0. If it did, null pointers would be unfortunately valid, making bugs involving accessing a null pointer that much harder to find.

Comment: Well if you cannot "use proc files *or any other method*" (emphasis added) then you cannot solve the problem.  Anything you do would constitute *some* method, even if one of your own devising.  I understand (I think) that you are not permitted to access files in the `/proc` filesystem, but otherwise the actual constraints on acceptible solutions are unclear.

Comment: Edit your question to improve it! Why can't you use `/proc/`?

Comment: Are you sure to understand well what the teacher is expecting from you? Could you give some more context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could read (from your program) the `/proc/self/maps` file. Try first the following two commands in a terminal

```
 cat /proc/self/maps
 cat /proc/$$/maps
```

<sup>(at least to understand what are the address space)</sup>

Then read [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) and of course wikipages about [processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29), [address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space), [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), [MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit), [shared memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory_%28interprocess_communication%29), [VDSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDSO).

If you want to share memory between two processes, read first [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html)

If you can't use `/proc/` (which is a pity) consider [mincore(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mincore.2.html)

You could also *non-portably* try reading from (and perhaps rewriting the same value using `volatile int*` into) some address and catching `SIGSEGV` signal (with a [sigsetjmp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sigsetjmp.3.html) in the signal handler), and do that in a -dichotomical- loop (in multiple of 4Kbytes) - from some sane start and end addresses (certainly not from 0, but probably from `(void*)0x10000` and up to `(void*)0xffffffffff600000`) 
 See [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html).

You could also use the Linux (Gnu libc) specific [dladdr(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dladdr.3.html). Look also into [ptrace(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) (which should be often used from some *other* process).

Also, you could study [elf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html) and read your own executable  [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) file. Canonically it is `/proc/self/exe` (a symlink) but you should be able to get its from the `argv[0]` of your `main` (perhaps with the convention that your program should be started with its full path name).

Be aware of [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) and disable it if your teacher permits that.

PS. I cannot figure out what your teacher is expecting from you.

Comment: The question specifies that "proc files" cannot be used.

Comment: I improved my answer to take that into account. Honestly, I don't understand the teacher. Using `/proc/` is so much more instructive!

Comment: I agree, I'm not sure what the point of the exercise is supposed to be.

Comment: I agree that this whole process seems odd, because everything I see online suggests going about it differently. I'm supposed to learn about signals, so your paragraph regarding the `non-portable` method seems right on the money. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

From a userland process's perspective, its address *space* starts at address `0x0`, but not every address in that space is valid or accessible for the process.  In particular, address `0x0` itself is never a valid address.  If a process attempts to access memory (in its address space) that is not actually assigned to that process then a segmentation results.

You could actually use the segmentation fault behavior to help you map out what parts of the address space are in fact assigned to the process.  Install a signal handler for `SIGSEGV`, and skip through the whole space, attempting to read something from somewhere in each page.  Each time you trap a SIGSEGV you know that page is not mapped for your process.  Go back afterward and scan each accessible page.

Do only read, however.  Do not attempt to write to random memory, because much of the memory accessible to your programs is the binary code of the program itself and of the shared libraries it uses.  Not only do you not want to crash the program, but also much of that memory is probably marked read-only for the process.

EDIT: Generally speaking, a process can only access its own (virtual) address space.  As @cmaster observed, however, there is a syscall (`ptrace()`) that allows some processes access to some other processes' memory in the context of the observed process's address space.  This is how general-purpose debuggers usually work.

Comment: @cmaster, good catch.  Debuggers use `ptrace()` to access child processes' memory (and otherwise to control them).  Under some circumstances, processes can traces others that are not their children, too.  Answer edited.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit more difficult than it seems at the first sight. In Linux every process has its own memory space. Using any arbitrary memory address points to the memory space of this process only. However there are mechanisms which allow one process to access memory regions of another process. There are certain Linux functions which allow this *shared memory* feature. For example take a look at 
[this link](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node27.html) which gives some examples of using shared memory under Linux using `shmget`, `shmctl` and other system calls. Also you can search for `mmap` system call, which is used to map a file into a process' memory, but can also be used for the purpose of accessing memory of another process.

Comment: I'm being a bit pedantic, I think, but a userland process can *never* access another process's address space if the system is working correctly.  Shared memory doesn't do that: it causes parts of two or more processes' separate address spaces to reference the same memory, but each process still accesses that memory via its own address space.  In particular, the address of a given chunk of shared memory is not necessarily the same for different processes accessing it.

Comment: @John Bollinger That's true. To clarify a little bit further. On e.g. x86 systems, both processes access the same physical addresses in the region of shared memory. CPU's paging mechanism is used to map a range of (so called virtual) addresses of a given process to a range of physical memory. Two different user processes can have different process' (virtual) memory addresses mapped to the same physical memory addresses.